# Devise. Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to log-in into my application from another web page. And I am getting:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for <IP>  at 2015-11-12 09:10:50 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"s8Juci8NHpiIhPtZMUycOjF0oEe4cmHsrVukMLHa9VJpbhRKX7P3uN1JnMPYHIGOse0aLa0ni/5nXh8qe8DUkA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"my_email@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

How can I make it work? 
I have tried different:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :sign_in
protect_from_forgery except: :sign_in
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:sign_in]
```

But it does not help. How can I skip CSRF token check on log-in and log-out?

Answer (score 2):

Skip verification of token in your controller Like this

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```